# Setting the background color on hovering a GridView column Header

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, hover

Should be simple and common enough: I want to override the hover color on a GridView ColumnHeader.

So I'm using `<GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle >`, a `<Trigger>` and a `<Setter>`, but it's completely ignored. It should be an ugly green, but no, it's some bluish color.
The Trigger is working though, if I add a Foreground property Setter, it does work.

What am I missing?

```
<ListView ...>
    ...
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" >
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle >
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" >
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MahApps.Brushes.Gray10}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
          </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
          <GridViewColumn  Header="NOT GREEN" Width="150" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    ...
</ListView>
```

Edit: I did some snooping, and I could track a ControlTemplate trigger on MouseOver that seems to take precedence. However, looking at the doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN), I'm unsure which is what in the order of precedence

> 3. Local values.
> 4. TemplatedParent
> 5. Implicit styles.
> 6. Style triggers.
> 7. Template triggers.
> 8. Style setter values.

According to this, I would have believed that my style trigger would take precedence over the ControlTemplate Trigger

Comment: You will need to check the default Style of GridViewColumnHeader, find out what makes the change and amend it if necessary.

Comment: But why? The trigger/setter should take precedence, no? Are there other properties that would change the background? I feel like I should not need to look at the original style to override bits of it, no?

Comment: Not necessarily. If those triggers were all on the same element, then yes. However, the background hover color could be on a different element in the control template. If the default control template's element is in front of your element (in terms of z-index) in the hierarchy, it's background will be shown since it is "on top" of whatever you are setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override the `Style` for the `GridViewColumnHeader.Template`, since that manages the background via other properties. The document linked below has all the xaml used to build out the control, so you can see why setting the background of the header doesn't help. The core issue is that the hover is set by the `VisualStateGroup` and not the template binding. So effectively that is overriding whatever MouseOver triggers you are setting.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Here is an example of that, leveraging the template provided in Microsoft's docs and modifying that for your needs, you might end up with something like what I have below. Note that this might be missing things from the built-in control, but you can add those back by just starting with what Microsoft has in the document linked above.

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="Gray" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContent"
                                                        Margin="0,0,0,1"
                                                        RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                            Margin="0,0,-9,0"
                                            Style="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderGripper}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                    Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="Green"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="Blue"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="NOT GREEN"
                                Width="150" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Since we are overriding the entire control, we need to add back the default `Thumb` (i.e. the column resizing grip) as such:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderGripper"
            TargetType="Thumb">
        <Setter Property="Width"
                Value="18" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Black">
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Background="Transparent">
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    Width="1"
                                    Fill="LightGray" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Result
[image]

Comment: That makes a whole lot of sense. Thanks for the complete answer, but more so the explanation!

Comment: Absolutely! Glad it helped :)